# zend framework 2 - ServiceManager error while saving data in database

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to create a saveAction in zend2 framework using doctrine.

in my PromotionsController i have this action:

```
public function saveLinkAction() {
    $view = new ViewModel();

    $salonId = (int) $this->params()->fromPost('salon_id', null);


    $addLink = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Promotions\Model\Link');

        $linkData['salon_id'] = $salonId;
        $linkData['link'] = '/link/example';

        $addLink->setData($linkData);        


    return $view;
}
```

This is just for learning how to write data in database.

```
$addLink = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Promotions\Model\Link');
```

This line of code is showing an error and i don't know what is the cause?

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Promotions\Model\Link
```

I have created a Link.php in Model directory.

```
<?php
namespace Link\Model;

use Application\Model\Entity;
use Zend\Form\Annotation;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="promo_link")
 */
class Link extends Entity {

    /********** PROPERTIES **********/

    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @var int
     * 
     * @Annotation\Exclude()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(name="salon", type="integer")
     * @var int 
     * 
     * @Annotation\Options({"label":"Salon"})
     * @Annotation\Validator({"name": "Digits"})
     */
    protected $salon;

    /**
     * @Column(name="link", type="string")
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $link;

     /**
     * @Column(name="start_date", type="string")
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $start_date;

     /**
     * @Column(name="end_date", type="string")
     * @var string 
     */
    protected $end_date;


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you where the problem is:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Promotions\Model\Link
```

Meaning: The ServiceManager doesn't know what `Promotions\Model\Link` is supposed to be. This key either doesn't exist in your SMConfig or while creating the instance to be returned some error occurs.

TL/DR - Check your ServiceManager Configuration regarding the key `Promotions\Model\Link`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should i check for this configuration?

Comment: Most likely within your `Module`-Class / `Module.php` - alternative point but unlikely could be `module.config.php`, too

Comment: Adding entities/models as service?

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your data in your database, you will need the entitymanager.

```
$link = new Link();
$link->setSalonId($salonId);
$link->setLink('/link/example');

$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$em->persist($link);
$em->flush();
```

You can start with the above code.

However, preferably you would create a repository and a servicelayer. The service should have access to the entityManager and hold your logic. Your controller should have access to this service.